Clarification regarding Account Deletion policy compliance
Understanding Google Play’s app account deletion requirements
Google Play’s data deletion badge and Data deletion area within the Data safety section give users a new set of transparency and controls over their user data while providing developers a way to showcase how they treat user data responsibly. If your app allows users to create an account from within your app, our User data policy requires that  it must also allow users to request for their account to be deleted.
getiing this message from play console for delete user account data
We need any login pannel for user to handle there data by him.
